# Fill inner part of an svg

Tags: svg

This is an svg of a circle with an X inside of it:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/>
  <path d="M14.59 8L12 10.59 9.41 8 8 9.41 10.59 12 8 14.59 9.41 16 12 13.41 14.59 16 16 14.59 13.41 12 16 9.41 14.59 8zM12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"/>
</svg>
```

I would like to change the color of the area around the X (not the X or the circle's border). Is there a way to do this? The solution I am looking for should work with any type of svg that contains an outline with something inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill="pink" d="M12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2z"/>
  <path d="M14.59 8L12 10.59 9.41 8 8 9.41 10.59 12 8 14.59 9.41 16 12 13.41 14.59 16 16 14.59 13.41 12 16 9.41 14.59 8zM12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully look at the second path definition you can spot `z` inside it - a "close sequence" symbol. That means there are actually 2 paths packed inside single `path` element. If you split them - there will be outline and "x" parts separately.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/>
  <path id="content" d="M14.59 8L12 10.59 9.41 8 8 9.41 10.59 12 8 14.59 9.41 16 12 13.41 14.59 16 16 14.59 13.41 12 16 9.41 14.59 8z" />
  <path id="outline" d="M12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"/>
</svg>
```

Note now that outline is also built from 2 paths - outer and inner. There are several different approaches to deal with it.

1) Split them, order outer-inner-content, fill outer with stroke color,
    fill inner with background color. The disadvantage is that image is
    no more transparent - inner is drawn on top of black outer.

2) Leave outline as is, duplicate inner part, add whatever fill you
    like, place content after both elements. Adds more bytes to the
    image.

3) Completely replace outline path with single stroke path of non-zero
    width. This is the best way, but not always possible, as outline
    shape can be not just a line. But for simplest cases (as yours)
    works perfectly

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/>
      <path id="content" d="M14.59 8L12 10.59 9.41 8 8 9.41 10.59 12 8 14.59 9.41 16 12 13.41 14.59 16 16 14.59 13.41 12 16 9.41 14.59 8z" />
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```